# Finding a value from array in File Path [Excel]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a little problem with Excel.
I'm trying to compare if one of several specific words occur in a path.
This is what I do with the following function:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($C$2:$C$4,A2)),"NO","YES")
```

However, the result is always "No".

Example data:
[image: Here is the table.]

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is well explained in this tutorial: https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SEARCH($C$2:$C$4,A2)
```

will return an array of a number or a `#VALUE!` errors.

If you wrap that in `ISNUMBER` it will return an array of `TRUE;FALSE...`

To see if ANY of the values are `TRUE`, wrap that in an `OR` and use that in your `IF` statement.

Of course, since this is an array formula, you have to enter it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$4,A2))),"Yes","No")
```

You can see what is happening by using the `Formula Evaluation` tool

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT with ISNUMBER and SEARCH

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C4,A2)))>0,"YES","NO")
```